# Resource ID while retrieving image from sdcard

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am trying to retrieve images in my listView from sdcard using AsyncTask and caching bitmaps
but i've run into following problem.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);
int resId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(pathArray.get(position),
"xyz",   context.getPackageName());
loadBitmap(resId, imageView);
```

Please tell me what should i put in place of "xyz"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the image is in the SD-card you have to load the actual image into a Bitmap to set to the ImageView.

the `getResources()` option is only for things that are inside the `res` folder in your project.

Comment: okay i understand that getResorces() is for res/ directory only but then what should be passed to loadBitmap my implementation is like      public void loadBitmap(int resId, ImageView view) {
  if (cancelPotentialWork(resId,view) ){
   final BitmapWorkerTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask(view);
   view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
   task.execute(resId);
  }
 }

Comment: please see @mrebval answer. He explained how to load an image from disk. You have to use a `File` to point to the location.

Answer (score 1):

This code get images from sdcard:

```
File cacheDir = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"folder_images");
File f = new File(cacheDir, "imageName");
FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(f);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
stream.close();
```